# Combine Traversal API and Gremlin

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

This might be a silly question.

I like traversal API because of the type safety I get from within my Java program, However am exploring the possibility of using it in conjunction with Gremlin API.

Something like roughly below. Am guessing this is not possible, But would like to know.

```
GraphTraversalSource g; // Get reference
g.V().has('author', 'name', 'Duke').injectGrooovy('SomeExternalGroovy').toList()
```

Comment: I think I know what you want to do, but just to be clear....what does `injectGroovy()` do? does that take a Groovy script as a string parameter to process "authors named Duke" vertices before returning a `List`?

Comment: @stephenmallette : Yes, thats precisely what I'd like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with a side-note....I wouldn't make a distinction between "Traversal API" and "Gremlin API" - that's not a comparison we typically make. There is a distinction between the Traversal API and the Graph API. The Traversal API is for users (like you) and the Graph API is for graph providers (like DSE Graph) who want to become TinkerPop enabled. The Traversal API is initialized through  `GraphTraversalSource`, typically named `g` whereas the Graph API is initialized through the `Graph`, typically named `graph`. You can see the javadoc for related classes in the Traversal API [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/package-summary.html) and the Graph API [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/package-summary.html). The Traversal API forms the steps that we think of in the [Gremlin language](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-traversal-steps).

The equivalent to `injectGroovy("SomeExternalGroovy")` is likely something akin to:

```
g.V().has('author','name','Duke').map(Lambda.function("it.get().value('name')"))
```

It basically passes a Groovy closure as a string into the `map()` step and the server will evaluate the string in the context of the server when it executes the traversal. I am assuming here of course that you are creating `g` through the `DseGraph` class like this:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = DseGraph.traversal();
```

If you were just submitting a string then you could just use Groovy directly do:

```
dseSession.executeGraph("g.V().has('author','name','Duke').map{it.get().value('name')"};
```

Note that you will need to enable lambdas in DSE Graph for any of this to work, by issuing a command like:

```
graph.schema().config().option("graph_name.traversal_sources.g.restrict_lambda").set(false)
```

Before you do any of that though you should ask yourself why you need to use a lambda. TinkerPop generally advises that you avoid lambdas in your Gremlin and only use them when there are no other options available to you. Gremlin is quite expressive and in most cases you can usually find appropriate Gremlin steps to replicate what you are doing in a lambda.

Comment: Thanks . I am a newbie to the whole graph space, so a using the terms a bit loosely, But I completely understand your explanation. However my use case is that in my system there is a notion of plugins that enrich a graphTraversal with its own processing.Plugins are in groovy-gremlin variant. My approach is convert groovy scripts to a String and call DseSession.executeGraph, but where I am struggling this to pipe these things together. (Is there a way to convert a DSE GraphResultSet to a GraphTraversal) and so I can just pipe the traversals from both the system and the plugins

Comment: That's basically what ` DseGraph.traversal()` does. Behind the scenes, a `GraphResultSet` is serialized to the traversers within a `GraphTraversal`. If you are using Groovy, i guess you could use groovy metaprogramming to add a client side step to `GraphTraversal` called `injectGroovy()` and then process the results locally there.

Comment: Sorry if I sound lame. My core system is all Java and we don't want to miss out on the type-safety on the core processing logics (atleast for now), Only the augmented graph processing provided by the plugins is in groovy and we would probably use `DseSession.executeGraph`. So metaprogramming may not be possible at the moment. Basically looking at calling groovy from Java code with a `GraphTraversal` binding and get back a `GraphTraversal`

Comment: hmm - when you say "convert groovy scripts to a String and call DseSession.executeGraph" are you saying you will take the string passed to `injectGroovy()` and then pass that string to `DseSession.executeGraph`? sorry - i sense i'm not connecting something here

Comment: Sorry, I think I mistlead with `injectGroovy`, It was only representational. What I'd like to do roughly is `GraphTraversal g = systemProcess(DseGraph.traversal(dseSession))` followed by `GraphTraversal enriched = callGraphStatementInGroovy(g, 'pathToGroovyFile')` where both `systemProcess` and `callAStatementInGroovy` are private methods in my Java Class

Comment: Once again thanks for your patience, Am only few days into DSE graph, so please bear with me.

Comment: Does the script in "pathToGroovyFile" just add more steps to `g`. In other words after `systemProcess()` the `g` variable might contain, `g.V().has('author','name','Duke')` and then `callGraphStatementInGroovy` executes "pathToGroovyFile" which takes that and adds extra steps so that you end up with `enriched` being `g.V().has('author','name','Duke').has('age',21)` - is that what it is doing? if not, then what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157496/discussion-between-sathyakumar-seshachalam-and-stephen-mallette).

Comment: Yes `callGraphStatementInGroovy` takes the `g` and adds the extra steps. The only catch is that the extra steps themselves are coming from an external groovy file and g is sent as a binding lets say "systemGraph" - So the groovy file will have the string systemGraph.has('age', 12)

Comment: i don't see any problem with doing that. just use the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` from the TinkerPop `gremlin-groovy` module in your `callGraphStatementInGroovy` method and pass `g` in as a binding along with your script from that file into the `eval()` method on the scriptengine. You'll get back a `GraphTraversal` from that and then you just have to execute it to get the results.

Comment: w00t!. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.